# Generates twice a string element in arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, random

I got a problem. in my quiz application in android studio.
So, when you start the quiz it should give questions randomly, but sometimes it appears 1 question twice.

```
public void updateQuestion(){
    int numOfQuestion = 0;
    while(true){
        int nxt = rng.nextInt(qsts.size());
        if(numOfQuestion < 10){
            if(!generated.contains(nxt)){
                generated.add(nxt);
                nextQuestion = qsts.get(nxt);
                question_tv.setText(nextQuestion.questionText);
                allAnswers.add(nextQuestion.correctAnswerText);
                allAnswers.add(nextQuestion.wrongAnswer1);
                allAnswers.add(nextQuestion.wrongAnswer2);
                allAnswers.add(nextQuestion.wrongAnswer3);
                Collections.shuffle(allAnswers);
                button1.setText(allAnswers.get(0));
                button2.setText(allAnswers.get(1));
                button3.setText(allAnswers.get(2));
                button4.setText(allAnswers.get(3));
                numOfQuestion++;
            }
        }else{
            //GameOver();
        }
    }
}
```

so my Class is:

```
public class QA {
    String questionText;
    String correctAnswerText;
    String wrongAnswer1;
    String wrongAnswer2;
    String wrongAnswer3;
    QA(String qst, String cAns, String wAns1, String wAns2, String wAns3){
        questionText = qst;
        correctAnswerText = cAns;
        wrongAnswer1 = wAns1;
        wrongAnswer2 = wAns2;
        wrongAnswer3 = wAns3;
    }
}
```

and the format of an object

```
QA q1 = new QA("Question", "CorrectAns", "WrongAns1", "WrongAns2", "WorngAns3");
```

I tried to remove the element which appears,

```
qsts.remove(generated);
```

or;

```
qsts.remove(nxt);
```

But the app crashed...
Also tried to create an empty ArrayList and to add the elements which are shown in multiple methods but again crashed.

Comment: Since, you require only unique questions, you can use a `Set`.

Comment: You can check if the list do not contains question then add it, otherwise do nothing

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on how is your collection `generated` implemented. I would recommend `HashSet<Integer>`.

For code efficiency, switch conditions - check for duplicates at first and then for number of questions.